# jquery selectbox : Reload Jquery Selectbox with other drop down values if last option is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectbox

How can I refresh jquery multiselect when the last option is selected with new values?
Like I have the below options in my selectbox

```
<select id="positions">
    <option value="0">Programmer</option>
    <option value="1">Tester</option>
    <option value="2">Manager</option>
    <option value="3">Admin</option>
    <option value="4">Load all other</option>    
</select>
```

If the user selects the "load all other" option from the select box, then this selectbox should be reinitialized with different values.
Or is it possible to populate two drop drop values in one selectbox separated using bold line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Part:

```
<select id="positions">
    <option value="0">Programmer</option>
    <option value="1">Tester</option>
    <option value="2">Manager</option>
    <option value="3">Admin</option>
    <option value="4">Load all other</option>    
</select>

<select id="positions2">
    <option value="0">test1</option>
    <option value="1">test2</option>
    <option value="2">test3</option>
    <option value="3">test4</option>
    <option value="4">Load all other</option>    
</select>
```

Jquery Part:

```
$('#positions').change(function() {
    if ($('#positions').val() == 4) {
        var data = $('#positions2').html();
        $('#positions').html(data );
    }
});
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uA62u/2/) example:

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you mean. Will this do the trick?

```
$('#positions').change(function() {
    if ($('#positions').val() === '4') {
        var newOptions = '<option value="0">Programmer</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="1">Tester</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="2">Manager</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="3">Admin</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="5">Helicopter Pilot</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="6">Fireman</option>';
        newOptions += '<option value="7">President of the United States</option>';
        $('#positions').html(newOptions);
    }        
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...but i need to put values from different drop down..reinitialize dropdown with other drop down values

Comment: Hmm. Will constructing a new string and then using the .html() function not work then? If not, then I'm not sure I understand the question. In my example, you don't have to include options 0-3.

Answer (score 0):

to load the $('#positions') with values from other selectBox

```
$('#positions').html( $('#otherSelectBox').html() );
```

but what if the same user still wants to see the previous choises? i think you should just append the $('#positions') with the next values and just hide the prev

```
$('#positions').children('option').hide().end().append( $('#otherSelectBox').html() );
```